# How to dynamically build a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

I want to create a function dynamically using javascript. I've started with the following:

```
function setFunc(setName){

    var  setName =  function () {
                    };

}
setFunc("totop");
```

I want to set a  function dynamically, but it doesn't work!

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't get why people are afraid of writing more than one-line questions. Characters are free and you will get more help if you write enough for people to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That won't work.

However, consider this: *functions in JavaScript are just values* and *window is the top-level scope*, so... (This assumes it is desired for the new function to be created in the top-level scope.)

```
function setFunc (name) {
    window[name] = function () { alert("hi!") }
}
setFunc("a")
window.a()    // "hi!" - explicit property access on object
window["a"]() // "hi!" - ditto
a()           // "hi!" - window implicit as top-level
```

However, *I do not* recommend this sort of global side-effect...

Happy coding.

Comment: It's not really a side-effect if you do it on purpose. (Not that I recommend doing this either.)

Comment: @nnnnnn It's a side-effect ... perhaps an expected one ;-)

Comment: avoid demonstrating around window globals; never assume in examples that code isn't being written in a closure, as no one writes globally anymore (except maybe you)

Answer (score 4):

The question is, in which context you want to create that function. If you really want to create a global function with that name, do it like

```
function setFunc( setName ) {
    this[ setName ] = function() {
        alert('I am ' + setName);
    };
}

setFunc('totop');
```

However, this is not a great idea to clobber the global object like that. Furthermore, the above code will break in es5 strict mode. However, by using the `new` keyword, you could create constructs like

```
new setFunc('foobar').foobar();
```

or just store the result in a variable

```
var myObj = new setFunc('BoyohboyWhatALongString');
console.log( myObj ); // BoyohboyWhatALongString() is in there now
```

Comment: How/why will it break in ES5 strict?

Comment: Or instead of using `new`, you explicitly create and return an object.

Comment: @pst: in es5 strict, `this` will be bound to `null` in that kind of function call. FelixKling: indeed.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** Use the eval function like this:

```
function setFunc(setName){
    eval (setName + " = function () { };");
}
setFunc("toTop");
```

You can access the window scope as an associative array and define the function with that name:

```
function setFunc (name) {
    window[name] = function () { }
}
```